# Rede Neural Perceptron Uma camada ,Entradas

Tags: python-3.x, loop

Olá
Estou com uma dúvida em relação a percorrera  entrada e peso de dado sem usar o numpy.

#AND

```
entrada = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]

peso = [0.0,0.0]
```

O calculo que fará é :  **entrada1 x  peso + entrada2 x peso  = 0**

na lp:

0 * 0.0 + 0 * 0.0  = **0.0**

Um loop para percorrer a lista e outro loop para sublistas.

```
exemplo loop usado :
for a in range(len(entrada)):
  calc = entrada[a][0] * peso +  entrada[a][1] * peso
```

até então o resultado é o desejado  mas se existir mais que 2 entradas como poderia ser o loop sem necessitar de calc = entrada[a][0] * peso +  entrada[a][1] * peso +  entrada[a][2] * peso

Em vez de especificar a posição alocar  diretamente, tento que fazer a multiplicação e somando com outra multiplicação.

em sintaxe é  multiplicar cada lista e somar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma mais fácil de fazer é utilizando a biblioteca **numpy**. Para instalar o numpy, execute:

```
pip install numpy   # ou pip3, dependendo do seu sistema
```

Após a instalação, é só utilizar:

```
import numpy

entrada = numpy.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
peso = numpy.array([0.0, 0.0])

resultado = entrada * peso.transpose()   # multiplicacao
saida = [sum(l) for l in resultado.tolist()]   #soma, usando list comprehension
```

Saída do programa:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Mudando os pesos só para testar:

```
peso = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0])
```

Saída com novos pesos:

```
[0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Conheço numpy é muito boa para rna, mas estou  procurando uma solução que não seja  lib externa, mas obrigado pela resposta.